# My type can be a string or a function, but typescript says that the functions are not callable

Tags: typescript

In my typescript file, I have a list of operations. Some of these are strings that needs to be executed and others are callable functions:

```
const operations: {title: string, method: Function | string}[] = [
      {
         title: `some powershell script`,
         method: `some powershell script`
      },
      {
         title: `function`,
         method: () => console.log("function"),
      }
];
if (typeof operations[i].method === `function`) {
     typeof operations[i].method() //  ERROR: This expression is not callable. No constituent of type 'string | Function' is callable.
}
if (typeof operations[i].method === `string`) {
     exec(operations[i].method) //  ERROR: Argument of type 'string | Function' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'string'.
}
```

Is there a way to resolve this typescript error without using **any**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about forcing the type using **as** ?

The complete code would be:

```
const operations: {title: string, method: Function | string}[] = [
      {
         title: `some powershell script`,
         method: `some powershell script`
      },
      {
         title: `function`,
         method: () => console.log("function"),
      }
];
if (typeof operations[i].method === `function`) {
     const op = operations[i].method as Function;
     typeof op();
}
if (typeof operations[i].method === `string`) {
     const op = operations[i].method as string;
     exec(op);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this idea very much. Found out I can even use exec(operations[i].method as string) without a const declaration for the string type.

Answer (score 0):

Create an additional variable to check against, for example with object destructuring within a loop:

```
for (const operation of operations) {

  const { method } = operation;

  if (typeof method === `function`) {
       method(); // Function
  }

  if (method === `string`) {
       exec(method); // string
  }

  // Or even simpler
  // typeof method === `function` ? method() : exec(method);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does indeed work in newer versions of TypeScript, as you verify it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play), so upgrading TypeScript would work.

However, the type `Function` is very generic, this is because you're using `any` implicitly for the return and `...args: any[]` for the arguments, so if you want to avoid using `any` at all costs, type the object as such:

```
{title: string, method: (() => unknown) | string}
```

If you know the exact type that the method will return, you can use other types aside from `unknown`, if you don't, `unknown` will say it has a consistent type, which is the same as "`any` excluding `never`".